# VBA Userform Checkbox Tracking

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, userform

I'm trying to create a VBA code to checkmark specific lube routes based on field data. My code works to generate a dynamic userform with the equipment number & part name as a checkbox.

My question is how do I then code the enter command button code to insert an "X" in the Done column?

My current code is below. The image of the sheet is also attached.[image]

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim curColumn   As Long
Dim LastRow     As Long
Dim i           As Long
Dim chkBox      As MSForms.CheckBox
Dim ctrl        As Control

curColumn = 1 'Set your column index here
LastRow = Worksheets("Monday").Cells(Rows.Count, curColumn).End(xlUp).Row

For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(ctrl) = "Checkbox" Then
        If ctrl.Value = True Then
             Worksheets("Monday").Cells(i, curColumn + 4).Value = "X"
        End If
    End If
    i = i + 1
Next ctrl
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
 
Dim curColumn   As Long
Dim LastRow     As Long
Dim i           As Long
Dim chkBox      As MSForms.CheckBox

curColumn = 1 'Set your column index here
LastRow = Worksheets("Monday").Cells(Rows.Count, curColumn).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastRow
    Set chkBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "CheckBox_" & i)
    chkBox.Caption = Worksheets("Monday").Cells(i, curColumn).Value & " " & 
Worksheets("Monday").Cells(i, curColumn + 2).Value
    chkBox.Left = 5
    chkBox.Top = 5 + ((i - 1) * 20)
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to your question is that you need to work out the row number `i`. You can achieve this by extracting it from the name of the checkbox (which was set when the form was initialised). After the line `If ctrl.Value = True Then` add the following line:

```
i = Val(Replace(ctrl.Name, "CheckBox_", ""))
```

`Replace(ctrl.Name, "CheckBox_", "")` removes the string "CheckBox_" from the name. For example if the name is "CheckBox_15", you will end up with the string "15". You then use `Val("15")` to evaluate the string "15" to the numeric value 15.

**Further Suggestions**

To help you make your code a little more dynamic, copy this function into a regular module:

```
Function GetColNo(sHeading As String, sSheetName As String, lHeadingsRow As Long) As Long
  Dim vHeadings As Variant
  Dim lLastCol As Long
  Dim j As Long
  
  With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sSheetName)
    lLastCol = .Cells(lHeadingsRow, Columns.Count).End(toleft).Column
    vHeadings = .Range(.Cells(lHeadingsRow, 1), .Cells(lHeadingsRow, lLastCol))
    GetColNo = 0
    For j = 1 To lLastCol
      If LCase(vHeadings(1, j)) = LCase(sHeading) Then
        GetColNo = j
        Exit Function
      End If
    Next j
  End With
  
End Function
```

Replace all the code in the userform module with this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim curColumn   As Long
    Dim LastRow     As Long
    Dim i           As Long
    Dim chkBox      As MSForms.CheckBox
    Dim ctrl        As Control
    
    ' ****
    Dim sSheetName  As String:  sSheetName = "Monday"
    Dim lDoneCol    As Long:    lDoneCol = GetColNo("Done", sSheetName, 1)
    
    ' No need for this now
    ' curColumn = 1 'Set your column index here
    ' ****
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sSheetName)
        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, lEquipNoCol).End(xlUp).Row
        
        For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
            If TypeName(ctrl) = "Checkbox" Then
                If ctrl.Value = True Then
                     ' *****
                     ' Extract the row number i
                     i = Val(Replace(ctrl.Name, "CheckBox_", ""))
                     ' *****
                     .Cells(i, lDoneCol).Value = "X"
                End If
            End If
            ' ****
            ' No need to increment i
            'i = i + 1
        Next ctrl
    End With
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
 
    Dim curColumn   As Long
    Dim LastRow     As Long
    Dim i           As Long
    Dim chkBox      As MSForms.CheckBox
    
    ' ****
    Dim sSheetName      As String:  sSheetName = "Monday"
    Dim lEquipNoCol     As Long:    lEquipNoCol = GetColNo("Equip No", sSheetName, 1)
    Dim lPartNameCol    As Long:    lPartNameCol = GetColNo("Part Name", sSheetName, 1)
    Dim lDoneCol        As Long:    lDoneCol = GetColNo("Done", sSheetName, 1)
    
    ' No need for this now
    ' curColumn = 1 'Set your column index here
    ' ****
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sSheetName)
        LastRow = Worksheets(sSheetName).Cells(Rows.Count, curColumn).End(xlUp).Row
        
        For i = 2 To LastRow
            Set chkBox = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "CheckBox_" & i)
            chkBox.Caption = .Cells(i, lEquipNoCol).Value & " " & .Cells(i, lPartNameCol).Value
            ' ****
            ' You probably should check the boxes if the corresponding value is X
            If UCase(.Cells(i, lDoneCol).Value) = "X" Then
                chkBox.Value = True
            End If
            ' ****
            chkBox.Left = 5
            chkBox.Top = 5 + ((i - 1) * 20)
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Unfortunaltely, I wasn't able to test the code so there might be a few typos/bugs, which you should easily be able to correct.

Hope it helps